# Debug native application on Samsung 4.4.2 "package is unknown" with run-as command

Tags: android

While trying to debug an Android native application via Eclipse on a Galaxy S4 i get a "package is unknown" error at the run-as command.

There's an open [issue at code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=58373) that states the problem it's related to the permission of the `/data/system/packages.list` file that has to be `rw-rw--r`, instead it `is rw-rw----`. So, on of the suggested solution is to root the phone and change the permissions.
I' ve rooted the phone to change permissions of packages.list file to `rw-rw--r` but when I start "Debug as native Application" from eclipse permissions are changed back to `rw-rw-------`.

How can I solve this? Do I have to flash back the firmware even if the phone is rooted?

Comment: Please format your question to make it more readable and provide some information about what's behind that link as it might go down in the future

Answer (score 2):

I have been breaking my head for several days as well now on this issue.
At the time of writing, I was able to debug native code on a Samsung phone with Android 4.1.2. However a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2 keeps confronting me with:

> gdbserver output:
>
> run-as: Package 'x.y.z' is unknown
>
> Verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1

As an "ugly" workaround, it seems possible to change the permissions of 'run-as' from 750 into 4750 on a rooted device; on a Windows 7 machine:

- connect your device with USB to the host PC
- open a command prompt on the host PC
- go to the platform-tools folder of the Android-sdk folder
- execute "adb shell"
- in the shell, do "sudo chmod 4750 /system/bin/run-as"

Theoretically this should solve the problem. I'm unable to test this however as I don't have a rooted device at the moment. *I would be happy to see if someone can actually test this and post a result.*

I found the following 2 references related to this issue very interesting:

- the [Android issue 58373](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=58373), my take-aways are:

  - google has patched this issue for Android 4.4. (see comment #51 and #52 of the referenced link, which provides the actual patches)
  - Samsung does seem to have a proper Android build and the respective patches might not have been included (see comment #76) (this statement might need some challenging)
- The [Samsung forum](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/native-debugging-still-broken-on-galaxy-devices/202/258621), my take-away:

  - Some people report that it has been fixed, some report that it hasn't.